# Calculate Dividends Return from Total & Price returns

Tags: dividends, rate-of-return, market-indexes

I understand `Price returns` and `Total returns` for stock indices. For example, total returns account for Dividends paid by the underlying stocks assuming they are reinvested back into the same. How do we calculate the embedded Dividend returns? The 2 choices are:

```
(1 + Price ret) * (1 + Dividend ret) = 1 + Total ret
```

OR,

```
Price ret + Dividend ret = Total ret
```

My calculations show that option II is the way to go, but I wanted to confirm with a broader audience. Returns can be since inception, or annualized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividends are not really "return" since the price of the index is reduced by the amount of the dividend, but the difference between the total return and the price return *as a function of the starting price* would be the total amount of dividends, since

```
    Rp = (P1 - P0)/P0
    Rt = (P1 - P0 + Div)/P0
==> Rd = Div/P0 = Rt - Rp
```

Note that this would not exactly equal the dividend *yield* of the index, since that is calculated from the price *at the time of the dividend*.